# Regular expression search and replace in multiple files (bulk) - without opening files

Tags: regex, replace, bulk

I normally use Notepad++ to search and replace what I need (regex), however, I have to open all the files that I need, in order to replace what is needed to be replaced..  My question is how can I do that in bulk (multiple) files, in a folder, without opening any of the files?  Is there a good freeware to do that with?  or something like creating .bat or .pl file, and run it in the folder to execute the replace?  If so, how can it be done?

Simple example:

```
<b>(\d+\. )</b>
```

to

```
\1
```

This regex removes the bold tag in numbers.
How can it be done for bulk files without using NP++ under Windows?

Comment: You can of course do it in any scripting language (like Perl). What did you try anyway?

Comment: I just installed Active Perl, but I don't know what I should write in the .pl file, to tell it to replace something with something in all the files in that directory, or files with certain extension.  However, I didn't know that NP++ does that.  But still I would love to know how to do it with Perl. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do it with Perl... then learn Perl ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use Notepad++'s own *Find in files* function, that you can find in the *Find* menu.

Comment: wow..  I didn't know that NP++ had that option.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @m0skit0, he wrote "without opening any of the files", not "without using N++ ;)
@ Mike: if it works for you, please accept the answer

Comment: @rock3r: I don't know if you have reading or sight issues, but he definitely states *How can it be done for bulk files **without using NP++** under Windows?* Mike: please next time do not take stuff for granted.

Comment: @m0skit0: oh, yeah. My understanding of that phrase has always been "given that I can't find a way to do it in N++, how do I do it without using it?"

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with this perl oneliner:

```
perl -pi.back -e 's#<b>(\d+\.\d+)</b>#$1#g;' file*
```

This will process all files that have their name beginning with `file` and save them before into  `fileX.back`.